# How we can use Sqoop hive and in a java program?

Tags: java, sql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

How I can import multiple tables to HDFS with Sqoop a java program (I tried with union but does not work because the tables do not have the same number of column).

Also how hive can be used to display given in HDSF using a java program.
Hive can be applied directly to the Oracle database or have to go through HDFS?

Comment: Can you post some of the code you have used?

Comment: options.setTargetDir(dfs.getWorkingDirectory() + "/TestDirectory");
        options.setHadoopMapRedHome("/hadoop-1.2.0");
        options.setFetchSize(0);
        options.setNumMappers(8);
        options.setSqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ACTIVATION where $CONDITIONS");
        options.setSplitByCol("REF_ICCID");
        options.setTargetDir(dfs.getWorkingDirectory() + "/TestDirectory1");

        int status = new ImportTool().run(options);
        System.out.println(status); @JeffSloyer

Comment: I can not import multiple tables at once?
and how I can use with hadoop hive to make select query